# responsive position absolute using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I have create a code snippet to demo my problem.

```css
img {
    border:1px solid;
}
.bubble1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:pink;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    left:45px;
}
.bubble2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:cyan;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:135px;
    left:155px;
}
.bubble3 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left:68px;
}
.bubble4 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:213px;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/62GOyK9.png" />
<div class="bubble1"></div>
<div class="bubble2"></div>
<div class="bubble3"></div>
<div class="bubble4"></div>
```

There are 4 boxes I want to map the positions on a background, and I did it using position absolute.

But the problem is it can't be responsive. On larger / smaller screen, the image stretched and the mapping became off target. How to solve my issue using javascript?

Answer (score -1):

```js
$(function (){
  var init_width = $(window).width();
  var all_div = $('div');
  var init_left = function (){
    var result = [];
    all_div.each(function (i){
    var left = parseInt($(all_div[i]).css('left'));
    result.push(left); 
    });
    return result;
  }();  
  $(window).resize(function (){  
    var width = $(window).width();
    all_div.each(function (i){
      var now_left = init_left[i]/init_width * width;
      $(all_div[i]).css('left',now_left);
    });
  });  
});
```

```css
img {
    border:1px solid;
}
.bubble1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:pink;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:65px;
    left:45px;
}
.bubble2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:cyan;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:135px;
    left:155px;
}
.bubble3 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:190px;
    left:68px;
}
.bubble4 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:220px;
    left:213px;
}
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="bubble1"></div>
<div class="bubble2"></div>
<div class="bubble3"></div>
<div class="bubble4"></div>
```

I make a draft [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gogitu/1/edit?js,console,output) to achieve the responsive layout. The key mind is:

1. when the DOM ready you could get a set of numbers of these div's `left`and then you must handle these data to percent for responsive
2. you should recalculate the window width when resize.

actually, when you work out the first key mind, you will make it. the** resize ** just make the DEMO have more adapted.

Comment: this is a cool solution! will the init work in different sizes of viewport?

Comment: @JamesLemon absolutely, the divs position depends on what your css style value is.

Comment: if u include the background image ur code isn't work actually, because the img's x move up and down besides left.

Comment: @JamesLemon It's easy. Just instead of **window width**, use the img width as reference.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need a javascript solution for this?

Why cant you use percentage in CSS position styles?

```css
img {
    border:1px solid;
}
.bubble1 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:pink;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top:15%;
    left:10%;
}
.bubble2 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:cyan;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    top: 30%;
    right:30%;
}
.bubble3 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:orange;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 30%;
    left:30%;
}
.bubble4 {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;
    opacity:0.8;
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    right:10%;
}
```

```html
<div class="bubble1"></div>
<div class="bubble2"></div>
<div class="bubble3"></div>
<div class="bubble4"></div>
```